# get form proterty `cannot explicitly call operator or accessor`

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm makeing a small app for wp7, and I'm haveing an error when I try to get from a reference.

The code in something like this:

```
   private void refreshExistingShellTile()
    {
        using (IEnumerator<ShellTile> enumerator = ShellTile.get_ActiveTiles().GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                ShellTile current = enumerator.get_Current();
                if (null != current.get_NavigationUri() && !current.get_NavigationUri().ToString().Equals("/"))
                {
                    Black_n_Gold.Entities.Tile tile = App.CurrentApp.tileService.findById(App.CurrentApp.tileService.getTileId(current.get_NavigationUri().ToString()));
                    if (tile != null && tile.id == this.customizedTile.id)
                    {
                        current.Delete();
                        this.createShellTile(this.customizedTile);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have this errors:

```
'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile.ActiveTiles.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor
'Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile.NavigationUri.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile>.Current.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor
```

I'm having the same error when I try to add or set from a property, and I looked on the web, but I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the underlying method names. Instead of this:

```
ShellTile current = enumerator.get_Current();
```

You want:

```
ShellTile current = enumerator.Current;
```

etc. However, I would *also* suggest using a `foreach` loop instead of explicitly calling `GetEnumerator` etc:

```
private void refreshExistingShellTile()
{
    foreach (ShellTile current in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
    {
        Uri uri = current.NavigationUri;
        if (uri != null && uri.ToString() != "/")
        {
            Black_n_Gold.Entities.Tile tile = App.CurrentApp.tileService
                .findById(App.CurrentApp.tileService.getTileId(uri.ToString());
            if (tile != null && tile.id == customizedTile.id)
            {
                current.Delete();
                createShellTile(customizedTile);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also note that .NET naming conventions would suggest that `findById` etc should be PascalCased:

- `FindById`
- `GetTileId`
- `CreateShellTile`

Comment: It worked, thanks... I'll chance the GetEnumerator for all the code and see if I have any other error

Comment: @SebastiánMiles: How did you come up with this code to start with? Was it decompiled from something?

Comment: I had this problem with decompiled code, the ILSpy decompiler gave me "Vector3.get_zero();", while the Reflector decompiler gave me "Vector3.zero;" - which worked.

Comment: @psychobrm: Yes, in IL it would show up as a method with metadata to show that the method is the getter for a property.