# Error: 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DbProviderFactory.get': cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I needed to make a change to my webAPI service and what happened was I lost my project files. I had the dll file so I decompiled the file and got my code back. When I tried to build the solution I got an error. 
Can anyone tell me why am I getting this error? 
The reference to Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data exist in my code.
I could not find what is it that causes the error.

The error occurs on the line:

```
DbCommand dbCommand = databaseObject.get_DbProviderFactory().CreateCommand();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DatabaseObject` type has a property for `DbProviderFactory`, something like:

```
public DbProviderFactory DbProviderFactory { get; set; }
```

In C# properties are compiled to a backing field and a `get_Foo()` and `set_Foo()` method. What you're seeing is the decompiled `get` accessor.

You can change it back to a property access instead of a method call:

```
DbCommand dbCommand = databaseObject.DbProviderFactory.CreateCommand();
```

This is also explained in among others [get form proterty `cannot explicitly call operator or accessor`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14185934/get-form-proterty-cannot-explicitly-call-operator-or-accessor) and [Unable to run Console Application in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444885/unable-to-run-console-application-in-c-sharp). And please start using version control to prevent the loss of source code.

Comment: I changed get_DbProviderFactory to DbProviderFactory but still nothing

Comment: @Victor I can't do anything with "still nothing".

Comment: Error: Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DbProviderFactory.get: cannot explicitly call operator or accessor

Comment: Where did the `.get` come from?

Comment: It worked fine I was doing it wrong. Thank you so much. I did not see that had DbProviderFactory().CreateCommand(); just deleted () and it worked fine :)